# downgrade java version

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation

I tried to downgrade java version.

If I use `apt-get install sun-java6-jdk` on Ubuntu, it will install java version `1.6.26` .

What I want is `java 1.6.20`. How can I downgrade java?

Comment: isn't this a question for http://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: @ʘleg: not sure...  There's an answer applying to all Linux systems and most Un*x systems too (besides OS X).  Don't know where this should be migrated (or if it should) that said...

Comment: @user988052 not all Linux systems have `apt-get` and word `downgrade` tells me that he already has java installed as an Ubuntu package so downgrading will involve at least removing the installed one I guess, but I have to agree with you if there's really no way to do get older java in Ubuntu way

Comment: If you are merely wanting to compile code compatible for version 1.6, just the cross-compilation options of javac (using a 1.6 rt.jar and JDK 1.6+).

Comment: @ʘleg: see my answer...  Whether he already has Java installed or not does not change the fact that you do not need to be *root* to install Java on Linux and that you can install as many different Java versions you want on Linux.  OP doesn't want to *"Use apt-get to install Java 1.6.20"*, he wrote that *"apt-get will install 1.6.26"*.  What he wants is to install 1.6.20 and my answer shows one way to do just that, and there's no need for *apt-get* ; )

Answer (score 15):

Java on Linux doesn't need to be installed as root.  You can install as many different Java versions you want on Linux, either in separate user accounts or in a single account.

I do it all the time (switching from one Java version to another) to test on various versions of the JVM.

Changing your Java version can be as simple as this:

```
... $  which  java
/home/b/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java

... $  export  PATH=/home/b/jdk1.6.0_25/bin:$PATH

... $  which  java
/home/b/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java
```

To fetch an old version, go to the "Oracle Java Archive" page (Google if link becomes broken):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

Then pick your poison.  I download the *.bin*, *chmod +x* it and then I extract the Java version I want from the *.tgz*.

Then I simply set the PATH and I'm usually good to go.

I run my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) using one Java version, I typically compile using another JDK and I test on several JVMs.

All this from the same user account.

So it's not as if you had to install "one" Java version on a Linux system...

Now, concretely, if I were you, I'd simply remove all traces from Java while being root, and then I'd download the old version I need from the Oracle Java Archive.

Comment: Didn't know that! Any chance this can be done on windows too just by changing the path? Or can it be 'hacked up' on windows?

Comment: @dann.dev: on Windows it used to be different because a long time ago (and I don't know if it changed since then) you **had** to have admin right on the Windows machine to be able to install Java.  So this is quite different from Linux where you can simply install Java with non-root accounts.  I mean, seen that on Linux you can install Java without being root you can be sure that you can install as many different Java as you want.  On the Windows side of the pond I've got no clue ; )

Answer (score 13):

like tactical coder said, you can install as many versions as you want, to switch the current version just run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And select the desired version.

If you wish, run it for javac and javaws:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac

sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

Source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps to **downgrade** **JAVA** here[JAVA14 to JAVA8]:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Now Select the version of JDK

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Now Select the version of JRE

**DONE**

Check if it is downgraded by

```
java -version
```

Comment: May need to reinstall the unifi package in order to install openjdk-8-jdk and then select the version

Comment: This helped me to downgrade the java version.
Thanks for all the steps

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from the [archive section for Java SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html).

Answer (score 1):

$sudo apt-get install **openjdk-8-jre** (replace with the version you want to install)

$sudo update-alternatives --config java
{will get the option to choose the alternative java on your machine}

**select the one you want to use as default**

$java -version
Check the java version

Answer (score 0):

I find Jenv to be the easiest way to switch between Java versions. You can set a Java version globally, or you can set it so that certain directories will use a specified version of Java. 
See their [website](http://www.jenv.be/)

once installed with Homebrew or cloned from github its as easy as:

jenv add /path/to/java1.6.20/home

jenv global 1.6.20