# After the upgrade jvm8 grails run-app does not start

Tags: grails

Ok, I decided to try in the framework grails. Installed it according to the  [manual](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-and-set-up-java-grails-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-linux-vps/.). 
Create a test project:

```
## grails create-app ~/workspace/grails/test-project
```

Run a test project:

```
## cd workspace/grails/test-project; grails run-app
```

It's ok.

Today, Ubuntu has offered to install the updates, update the package java-8-oracle-installer. After performing this update command

```
## cd workspace/grails/test-project; grails run-app
```

result:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not copy a non-root Method
at java.lang.reflect.Method.copy(Method.java:151)
... 157 more мар 06, 2015 2:28:54 PM org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM copyMethod SEVERE: Problems copying method. Incompatible JVM?
```

I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880781/incompatible-jvm-in-ggts-eclipse-and-java-1-8 take a look at some stuff I put together here  https://github.com/vahidhedayati/documentation/blob/master/grails/grails3-intellij.md - and try loading up your app using your older JVM - you will need to configure your jvm to be your older version which should still reside under /usr/lib/jvm

Comment: In my case it worked after using JDK 1.8.0_31 instead of 1.8.0_74 (on Mac OS).

Answer (score 8):

Replace the springloaded-1.2.1-release.jar with springloaded-1.2.4.jar and that would fix the issue.

cd your GRAILS_HOME/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars

Remove springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar

And do 
`wget https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/springloaded/1.2.4.RELEASE/springloaded-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar -O springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar`

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/98) and [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/619)

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using Jdk1.8 version use jdk1.7.

It will work for you...