# Setting up IntelliJ environment to run old grails 2.4.2 code

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, setup-project

Using IntelliJ and trying the setup the environment to run "legacy" code running on Grails 2.4.2
Upgrading is not in the plans for the moment. So to do some small changes I need the recreate the environment.

I recreated the environment as close as possible by picking Groovy or Grail options.
But I get a compile error stating it's unable to compile groovy code.

I made sure to have on **Settings -> Build Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler** to run on bytecode version 7 (I'm using JDK 8 from Amazon Corretto).

Also on **Project Structure-> Modules (Dependencies Tab)**

- (by default) corretto-1.8 (scope: blank)
- grails-2.4.2 (scope: Provided)
- Grails User Library ("project name") (scope: Compile)

On the **Sources Tab** I have the correct location of the source code; Confirmed in the **Paths tab**

I have InteliJ IDEA 2022.2.5 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are changes needed to replace some of the groovy files in %GRAILS_HOME%/lib
Read following article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896863/after-the-upgrade-jvm8-grails-run-app-does-not-start

Answer (score 0):

I found a missing configuration piece under Tools -> Grails -> Configure Grails SDK

Once you click it you are asked to pick the project name and the location of the grails libraries (I assume that picks up the missing groovy compiler):

[image]

Once that was set I could run **grails clean-all**, **grails refresh-dependencies** and **grails compile**