# Debug Grails Application in GGTS 3.6.4, nothing happens, no error message

Tags: debugging, grails, ggts

I'm trying to debug my grails application (grails 2.5.0) with ggts 3.6.4. It worked several times before without any problem but now just nothing happens. I rightclick the project, then `Debug As Grails command Run App`

The console is just showing pretty standard stuff which appears everytime I run the app too:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
objc[7403]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
|Loading Grails 2.5.0
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
...............................................
|Running Grails application
objc[7415]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Pretty strange is that it worked several times before and I don't really know what could've changed since I got the same project as my friends from git.

Comment: Great thing with Java is the verbosity in errors it produces. It tells you JavaLauncher is implemented twice.. You have issues with your JDK config i.e. maybe its been implemented across two jdks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794573/objc10012-class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-libinstrument-dyl  -- try doing a clean and also look into the jdk config of your ide

Comment: I think this message is bug since I just installed my java on a clean OS, a few posts here confirmed that. I did a clean but that didnt help either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880781/incompatible-jvm-in-ggts-eclipse-and-java-1-8 try this post it maybe related to 8.0_45