# Grails not working in GGTS 3.6.4

Tags: grails, ggts

I have downloaded the `GGTS 3.6.4` from https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all . 
for `Windows 64 bit` version . I tried creating a sample `Grails` project. But i'm getting the below error.
`Java JDK 1.8_40` is configured in my machine.

```
Error creating grails process
Timeout: Grails process did not produce output for over 20300 milliseconds
```

I have no `proxy` problems either.

Comment: Can you able post your full `stacktrace`? And please make sure that you are not under proxy. Also did you tried with any other other version of `GGTS`?

Comment: @Suganthan , I have got only that error in a window and apart from that it showed me the below error also.    Command terminated with an exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jps": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified (see details for partial output)
Cannot run program "jps": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
------System.out:-----------
 Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
------System.err:-----------

Comment: Which version of Grails?

Comment: 2.4.4 which is coming by default with GGTS 3.6.4

Comment: I believe you need to use JDK 1.7 with Grails 2.4.4. I had the same issue. Or 1.8_31. I think...

Comment: I am trying with JDK 1.7 with newly installed GGTS 3.6.4 version. But it looks so odd as to why i can't even create a sample Hello World project. Grails really hurts !!!!

Comment: I got ggts fully working with JDK 1.8_065. To make it work get hold of http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/springloaded/1.2.5.RELEASE/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar  Put this into grails-2.4.4/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/
Re-launch GGTS 
There is another thread here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880781/incompatible-jvm-in-ggts-eclipse-and-java-1-8 but this covers older version of springloaded which did not work properly under the latest 8. Your issue relates to something else.  Try grails command wizard and launch command with --stacktrace on the end

Comment: @vahid... Thanks. I shall try the same and confirm once after it works.