# Cannot run Grails application in Grails/Groovy Tool Suite 3.6

Tags: grails, ggts

This is the error that I am getting when I try to start the application:

```
grails console
Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpathDec 24, 2015 11:14:34 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
....................................
|Running Grails application
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\grails3.6\ggts-bundle\grails-2.4.4\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: I think here the issue is access rights to that folder files. Try to extract your   GGTS in your local drive rather than in your OS drive.

Comment: See it says springreloaded jar manifest  is missing. Try working from any other drive rather than C.

Answer (score 4):

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\grails3.6\ggts-bundle\grails-2.4.4\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar

This question is old but I struggled the same problem yesterday. The solution was to copy grails or your whole GGTS-Bundle to a location without any spaces in it's name. In addition you might need to update the springloaded.jar since there are a errors with a few JDK versions. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/98) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351759/3250397) for help.