# JVM Crashing for Grails 2.4.2 application while upgrading from Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: java, grails, java-8, mysql-5.7, grails-2.4

Following are the configurations that our current application:

Grails 2.4.2
Java: jdk-7u80
MySQL: 5.7
Tomcat: 7
MySQLConnector: 5.1.39

Now I am trying to upgrade Java 8 from Java 7.

I am trying with the "jdk-8u25" version(To avoid issue mentioned in [Incompatible JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880781/incompatible-jvm-in-ggts-eclipse-and-java-1-8))

After upgrade: Whenever the application tries to access Database then JVM is crashing.

Crash Report is:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000054e6bfa4, pid=10320, tid=15596
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3ebfa4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001a06e000):  JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=15596, stack(0x000000001a890000,0x000000001a990000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000018

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000001b8e1ea0, RCX=0x000000001a98ece0, RDX=0x000000001b8e1ea0
RSP=0x000000001a98ec80, RBP=0x000000001a98ed90, RSI=0x000000001a98ece0, RDI=0x000000001b8e1ea0
R8 =0x000000001a98ece0, R9 =0x000000001b8e1ea0, R10=0x000000001b8e1710, R11=0x000000002156a070
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x000000001b8e1e40
RIP=0x0000000054e6bfa4, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001a98ec80)
0x000000001a98ec80:   000000001af34480 0000000054e73e57
0x000000001a98ec90:   0000000000000001 000000001b8e19b0
0x000000001a98eca0:   000000001a98f020 0000000054e73d10
0x000000001a98ecb0:   00000000550b0208 000000002156a300
0x000000001a98ecc0:   000000001a98f020 000000000000002a
0x000000001a98ecd0:   000000001b8e1e40 0000000054e69d9e
0x000000001a98ece0:   00000000550b0038 000000001a98f320
0x000000001a98ecf0:   000000001b8e1ea0 0000000000000065
0x000000001a98ed00:   0000000000000000 0000000054e76dca
0x000000001a98ed10:   0000000000000000 000000001a98f020
0x000000001a98ed20:   000000001b8e1ea0 0000000000000000
0x000000001a98ed30:   000000000000002a 0000000000000001
0x000000001a98ed40:   000000001a98f020 0000000000000001
0x000000001a98ed50:   000000001b8e1c80 0000000054e80f89
0x000000001a98ed60:   000000001e86e485 00000000000000aa
0x000000001a98ed70:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000054e6bfa4)
0x0000000054e6bf84:   cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 89 74 24
0x0000000054e6bf94:   18 57 48 83 ec 20 48 8b 42 70 48 8b f1 48 8b fa
0x0000000054e6bfa4:   48 8b 48 18 48 8b 01 ff 50 18 84 c0 0f 84 bc 00
0x0000000054e6bfb4:   00 00 48 8b 47 70 48 89 5c 24 30 48 89 6c 24 38 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000001b8e1ea0 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000001a98ece0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a06e000
RDX=0x000000001b8e1ea0 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001a98ec80 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a06e000
RBP=0x000000001a98ed90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a06e000
RSI=0x000000001a98ece0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a06e000
RDI=0x000000001b8e1ea0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000001a98ece0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001a06e000
R9 =0x000000001b8e1ea0 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000001b8e1710 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000002156a070 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000001b8e1e40 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000001a890000,0x000000001a990000],  sp=0x000000001a98ec80,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x3ebfa4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3f3d10]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3f6dca]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3fd542]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3fde9d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3fe292]
V  [jvm.dll+0x403345]
V  [jvm.dll+0x403450]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3ed398]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3ed601]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3ed7c2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3ed98e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3edb8f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x98a02]
V  [jvm.dll+0x991f3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x22bde4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2852fa]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21d9f]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21e3b]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x17974]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6a271]


Current CompileTask:
C1: 138464 16747   !   3       com.mygrailsapp.test.EmailDomainService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f86a1f5f::getCallback (374 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000020441800 JavaThread "Thread-24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17468, stack(0x0000000039620000,0x0000000039720000)]
  0x000000002043e800 JavaThread "http-nio-8443-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=19980, stack(0x0000000039520000,0x0000000039620000)]
  0x0000000020443000 JavaThread "http-nio-8443-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3420, stack(0x0000000039420000,0x0000000039520000)]
  0x0000000020445000 JavaThread "http-nio-8443-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=17676, stack(0x0000000039320000,0x0000000039420000)]
  0x0000000020444800 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5116, stack(0x0000000039220000,0x0000000039320000)]
  0x0000000020437000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7580, stack(0x0000000039120000,0x0000000039220000)]
  0x000000002043d800 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1364, stack(0x0000000039020000,0x0000000039120000)]
  0x0000000020436000 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12792, stack(0x0000000038f20000,0x0000000039020000)]
  0x000000002043c000 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5552, stack(0x0000000038e20000,0x0000000038f20000)]
  0x0000000020439000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21596, stack(0x0000000038b20000,0x0000000038c20000)]
  0x000000002043a000 JavaThread "grails.plugin.cache.ehcache.GrailsEhCacheManagerFactoryBean$ReloadableCacheManager@19afda2d" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2584, stack(0x0000000038620000,0x0000000038720000)]
  0x0000000020438800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15680, stack(0x0000000037350000,0x0000000037450000)]
  0x000000001e6a2000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2172, stack(0x0000000035c90000,0x0000000035d90000)]
  0x000000001e6a6000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4224, stack(0x0000000035b90000,0x0000000035c90000)]
  0x000000001e69a000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16012, stack(0x0000000035a90000,0x0000000035b90000)]
  0x000000001e6a1800 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=18212, stack(0x0000000035190000,0x0000000035290000)]
  0x0000000023f8c800 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=8280, stack(0x0000000035090000,0x0000000035190000)]
  0x0000000023f8b800 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=18660, stack(0x0000000034f90000,0x0000000035090000)]
  0x0000000023f8b000 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=2932, stack(0x0000000034e90000,0x0000000034f90000)]
  0x0000000023f8a000 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=17356, stack(0x0000000034d90000,0x0000000034e90000)]
  0x0000000023f88000 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=18680, stack(0x0000000034c90000,0x0000000034d90000)]
  0x0000000023f87000 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=22968, stack(0x0000000034b90000,0x0000000034c90000)]
  0x0000000023f89800 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=9772, stack(0x0000000034a90000,0x0000000034b90000)]
  0x0000000023f88800 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-3" [_thread_in_native, id=11064, stack(0x0000000034990000,0x0000000034a90000)]
  0x0000000023f7f800 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=2976, stack(0x0000000034890000,0x0000000034990000)]
  0x0000000023f86800 JavaThread "quartzScheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=6988, stack(0x0000000034790000,0x0000000034890000)]
  0x0000000023f85800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6984, stack(0x0000000034490000,0x0000000034590000)]
  0x0000000023f85000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16784, stack(0x0000000034390000,0x0000000034490000)]
  0x0000000023f7f000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21148, stack(0x0000000033200000,0x0000000033300000)]
  0x0000000023f7e000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18752, stack(0x0000000032e50000,0x0000000032f50000)]
  0x0000000023f80800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15700, stack(0x0000000031f50000,0x0000000032050000)]
  0x0000000023f82000 JavaThread "grails.plugin.cache.ehcache.GrailsEhCacheManagerFactoryBean$ReloadableCacheManager@19afda2d" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16792, stack(0x0000000030280000,0x0000000030380000)]
  0x0000000023e57800 JavaThread "com.mygrailsapp.test.domain.Country.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6324, stack(0x000000002fb80000,0x000000002fc80000)]
  0x0000000023e54000 JavaThread "com.mygrailsapp.test.domain.AuditLog.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17944, stack(0x000000002f880000,0x000000002f980000)]
  0x0000000023e52800 JavaThread "com.mygrailsapp.test.domain.State.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21980, stack(0x000000002f180000,0x000000002f280000)]
  0x0000000023e55800 JavaThread "com.mygrailsapp.test.domain.security.Role.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22576, stack(0x000000002ee80000,0x000000002ef80000)]
  0x0000000023e51800 JavaThread "com.mygrailsapp.test.domain.ExternalSystem.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3324, stack(0x000000002e7b0000,0x000000002e8b0000)]
  0x000000001d037800 JavaThread "org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15244, stack(0x000000002e4b0000,0x000000002e5b0000)]
  0x000000001d03c800 JavaThread "org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3096, stack(0x000000002e1b0000,0x000000002e2b0000)]
  0x000000001d038000 JavaThread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@d207ae3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3568, stack(0x000000002ddc0000,0x000000002dec0000)]
  0x000000001e6a3800 JavaThread "mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1664, stack(0x000000002d8c0000,0x000000002d9c0000)]
  0x000000001e6a5000 JavaThread "PoolCleaner[885284298:1566484434122]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16108, stack(0x000000002d7c0000,0x000000002d8c0000)]
  0x000000001e699000 JavaThread "AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19772, stack(0x0000000026ce0000,0x0000000026de0000)]
  0x000000001e69a800 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4956, stack(0x00000000267e0000,0x00000000268e0000)]
  0x000000001e698800 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=21036, stack(0x00000000266e0000,0x00000000267e0000)]
  0x000000001e697000 JavaThread "AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23276, stack(0x0000000025bb0000,0x0000000025cb0000)]
  0x000000001d03e000 JavaThread "FileSystemWatcher: files=#1927 cl=java.net.URLClassLoader@51a16adf" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12532, stack(0x0000000024b40000,0x0000000024c40000)]
  0x000000001cc31000 JavaThread "NonBlockingInputStreamThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20628, stack(0x000000001da20000,0x000000001db20000)]
  0x000000001a12e800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17192, stack(0x000000001a990000,0x000000001aa90000)]
=>0x000000001a06e000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=15596, stack(0x000000001a890000,0x000000001a990000)]
  0x000000001a06c800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8520, stack(0x000000001a790000,0x000000001a890000)]
  0x000000001a06b800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14376, stack(0x000000001a690000,0x000000001a790000)]
  0x000000001a06b000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13796, stack(0x000000001a590000,0x000000001a690000)]
  0x0000000019fb8000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11908, stack(0x000000001a490000,0x000000001a590000)]
  0x0000000019fb7000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21576, stack(0x000000001a390000,0x000000001a490000)]
  0x0000000002f13000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3028, stack(0x0000000019e90000,0x0000000019f90000)]
  0x0000000002f12800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18728, stack(0x0000000019d90000,0x0000000019e90000)]
  0x0000000002e22800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=9052, stack(0x0000000002b50000,0x0000000002c50000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000017f88800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000019c90000,0x0000000019d90000] [id=6360]
  0x000000001a131800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001aa90000,0x000000001ab90000] [id=1268]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 464896K, used 221567K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 238080K, 21% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d8806ec0,0x00000000e3e00000)
  from space 226816K, 74% used [0x00000000f2280000,0x00000000fc858e60,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 230400K, 0% used [0x00000000e3e00000,0x00000000e3e00000,0x00000000f1f00000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 696802K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 89% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000aa878a60,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 264728K, capacity 270807K, committed 271024K, reserved 1302528K
  class space    used 15810K, capacity 17558K, committed 17584K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000122e0000,0x00000000126f0000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011ee0000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005525d490
 Begin Bits: [0x00000000131a0000, 0x00000000151a0000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000000151a0000, 0x00000000171a0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001460000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=55960Kb max_used=58636Kb free=189799Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002f20000, 0x00000000068e0000, 0x0000000011f20000]
 total_blobs=13118 nmethods=12228 adapters=801
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 138.367 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 nmethod 16746 0x00000000039a8110 code [0x00000000039a8260, 0x00000000039a8370]
Event: 138.370 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 16749       3       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember::getAnnotation (18 bytes)
Event: 138.371 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 nmethod 16749 0x0000000004d92f10 code [0x0000000004d930a0, 0x0000000004d93548]
Event: 138.375 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 16750       3       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationMap::get (21 bytes)
Event: 138.375 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 nmethod 16750 0x000000000602b0d0 code [0x000000000602b240, 0x000000000602b5a8]
Event: 138.380 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 16753       3       org.springframework.core.OrderComparator::compare (71 bytes)
Event: 138.380 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 nmethod 16753 0x00000000033774d0 code [0x0000000003377680, 0x0000000003377d38]
Event: 138.384 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 16751       1       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings::getAnnotationIntrospector (5 bytes)
Event: 138.385 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 nmethod 16751 0x0000000004b71650 code [0x0000000004b717a0, 0x0000000004b718b0]
Event: 138.391 Thread 0x000000001a06e000 16747   !   3       com.mygrailsapp.test.EmailDomainService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f86a1f5f::getCallback (374 bytes)

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 73.867 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=75 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 473600K, used 419990K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 271872K, 100% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e5f00000,0x00000000e5f00000)
  from space 201728K, 73% used [0x00000000e5f00000,0x00000000eefa58e8,0x00000000f2400000)
  to   space 204800K, 0% used [0x00000000f3800000,0x00000000f3800000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 660280K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 84% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000a84ce2a0,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 252634K, capacity 258015K, committed 258352K, reserved 1292288K
  class space    used 14635K, capacity 16140K, committed 16176K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 73.923 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=75 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 480768K, used 161136K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 275968K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e6300000)
  from space 204800K, 78% used [0x00000000f3800000,0x00000000fd55c318,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 211456K, 0% used [0x00000000e6300000,0x00000000e6300000,0x00000000f3180000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 660288K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 84% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000a84d02a0,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 252634K, capacity 258015K, committed 258352K, reserved 1292288K
  class space    used 14635K, capacity 16140K, committed 16176K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 75.191 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=76 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 480768K, used 437104K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 275968K, 100% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e6300000,0x00000000e6300000)
  from space 204800K, 78% used [0x00000000f3800000,0x00000000fd55c318,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 211456K, 0% used [0x00000000e6300000,0x00000000e6300000,0x00000000f3180000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 660288K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 84% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000a84d02a0,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 254423K, capacity 259993K, committed 260144K, reserved 1292288K
  class space    used 14834K, capacity 16394K, committed 16432K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 75.253 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=76 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 439808K, used 163494K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 275968K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e6300000)
  from space 163840K, 99% used [0x00000000e6300000,0x00000000f02a9b08,0x00000000f0300000)
  to   space 217088K, 0% used [0x00000000f2c00000,0x00000000f2c00000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 674878K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 86% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000a930f800,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 254423K, capacity 259993K, committed 260144K, reserved 1292288K
  class space    used 14834K, capacity 16394K, committed 16432K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 76.570 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=77 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 439808K, used 439462K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 275968K, 100% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e6300000,0x00000000e6300000)
  from space 163840K, 99% used [0x00000000e6300000,0x00000000f02a9b08,0x00000000f0300000)
  to   space 217088K, 0% used [0x00000000f2c00000,0x00000000f2c00000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 674878K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 86% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000a930f800,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 257016K, capacity 262613K, committed 262704K, reserved 1296384K
  class space    used 15107K, capacity 16687K, committed 16688K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 76.620 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=77 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 471552K, used 166620K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 254464K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e4e00000)
  from space 217088K, 76% used [0x00000000f2c00000,0x00000000fceb7098,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 222208K, 0% used [0x00000000e4e00000,0x00000000e4e00000,0x00000000f2700000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 682550K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 87% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000a9a8d9e0,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 257016K, capacity 262613K, committed 262704K, reserved 1296384K
  class space    used 15107K, capacity 16687K, committed 16688K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 77.575 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=78 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 471552K, used 421084K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 254464K, 100% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e4e00000,0x00000000e4e00000)
  from space 217088K, 76% used [0x00000000f2c00000,0x00000000fceb7098,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 222208K, 0% used [0x00000000e4e00000,0x00000000e4e00000,0x00000000f2700000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 682550K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 87% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000a9a8d9e0,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 260928K, capacity 266829K, committed 266928K, reserved 1298432K
  class space    used 15371K, capacity 17014K, committed 17072K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 77.626 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=78 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 422912K, used 168248K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 254464K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e4e00000)
  from space 168448K, 99% used [0x00000000e4e00000,0x00000000ef24e2c8,0x00000000ef280000)
  to   space 226816K, 0% used [0x00000000f2280000,0x00000000f2280000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 690947K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 88% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000aa2c0fe8,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 260928K, capacity 266829K, committed 266928K, reserved 1298432K
  class space    used 15371K, capacity 17014K, committed 17072K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 138.210 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=79 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 422912K, used 422712K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 254464K, 100% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e4e00000,0x00000000e4e00000)
  from space 168448K, 99% used [0x00000000e4e00000,0x00000000ef24e2c8,0x00000000ef280000)
  to   space 226816K, 0% used [0x00000000f2280000,0x00000000f2280000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 690947K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 88% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000aa2c0fe8,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 263801K, capacity 269769K, committed 269872K, reserved 1302528K
  class space    used 15690K, capacity 17426K, committed 17456K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 138.268 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=79 (full 7):
 PSYoungGen      total 464896K, used 169827K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 238080K, 0% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e3e00000)
  from space 226816K, 74% used [0x00000000f2280000,0x00000000fc858e60,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 230400K, 0% used [0x00000000e3e00000,0x00000000e3e00000,0x00000000f1f00000)
 ParOldGen       total 782848K, used 696802K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000afc80000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 782848K, 89% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000aa878a60,0x00000000afc80000)
 Metaspace       used 263801K, capacity 269769K, committed 269872K, reserved 1302528K
  class space    used 15690K, capacity 17426K, committed 17456K, reserved 1048576K
}

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 138.388 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d7505bc0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.389 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d7507518) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.389 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d75092a8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.389 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d7536758) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.389 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d7538200) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.389 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d753a120) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.390 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d7541640) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.390 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d7548060) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.390 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d754ab70) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 138.391 Thread 0x0000000023f87000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/AbstractEventTriggeringInterceptorCustomizer> (0x00000000d7646de8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfiåáN3nLa@

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx2048M -Xms64M -javaagent:C:/Work/tools/grails-2.4.2/bin/../lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded=""profile=grails;cacheDir=C:\Users\guest/.grails/2.4.2/" -Dprogram.name= -Dgrails.home=C:\Work\tools\grails-2.4.2\bin\.. -Dgrails.version=2.4.2 -Dbase.dir=. -Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\Work\tools\grails-2.4.2\bin\..\conf\groovy-starter.conf 
java_command: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --conf C:\Work\tools\grails-2.4.2\bin\..\conf\groovy-starter.conf --classpath   run-app -https
java_class_path (initial): C:\Work\tools\grails-2.4.2\bin\..\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.3.3.jar;C:\Work\tools\grails-2.4.2\bin\..\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.4.2.jar;C:/Work/tools/grails-2.4.2/bin/../lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 142 stepping 11, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 20813556k(10808440k free), swap 24352500k(11362804k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_25-b18), built on Oct  7 2014 14:25:37 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

Same issue is occurs from command-line **grails run-app** and IntelliJ IDEA as well.

Comment: It's working fine for me using: Grails 2.3.11, Java 8 (1.8.0_151 using the fix in incompatible JVM), Mysql connector 5.1.45 and Tomcat 8. Just to let you know it's doable, but hard to tell your problem. Maybe not "grails.project.target.level = 1.8" in BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: "Just to let you know it's doable..." - There are things in the framework that will not work.  If you are going to run a Grails 2.4 app in Java 8, you are hoping that your app doesn't execute any of those code paths.

Comment: We didn't officially add support for Java 8 until Grails 2.5.  In fact, that is one of the primary reasons 2.5 exists.  We were moving on to Grails 3 and weren't going to keep evolving 2.x but wanted a version of 2.x that supported Java 8 before we moved away from prioritizing Grails 2 work.  Grails 2.5 is that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JVM Crashing for Grails 2.4.2 application while upgrading from Java 7
>   to Java 8

Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we support Java 8.

Comment: I was surprised to find this answer as our project is running Java 8 with Grails 2.4.5. Also this site: https://objectpartners.com/2015/05/14/list-of-groovy-versions-for-each-version-of-grails/#:~:text=I%20started%20with%20Grails%201.2,and%20only%20included%20full%20releases.&text=*First%20version%20officially%20compatible%20with%20Java%208.  claims support started at 2.4.  What is correct?  I am interested because we continue to use 2.4.5 and I am searching another compatibility solution.

Comment: "What is correct? " - It might depend on what "support" means.  Grails 2.5 is the first version for which I would say that we officially offered support for Java 8.  When we released 2.5 we addressed some known issues that were problematic for some features in earlier versions of Grails when used with Java 8.