# IntelliJ ignoring project SDK and using the wrong Java version

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails

I know [how to set the project SDK](https://mkyong.com/intellij/how-to-change-the-intellij-idea-jdk-version/), and that's set to JDK 1.7, but when my app runs it appears to be using JDK 1.8.

[image]

Furthermore, InteliJ seems to start with the right JVM.
[image]

However, after a few seconds of running it presents an endless series of errors like this, which you would expect if it was using Java 1.8 as described in this answer: [Incompatible JVM in GGTS (Eclipse) and JAVA 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28887888/715608)

```
Oct 27, 2020 11:46:17 AM org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM copyMethod
SEVERE: Problems copying method. Incompatible JVM?
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM.copyMethod(JVM.java:134)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.createJavaMethod(OriginalClassInvoker.java:68)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.init(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:181)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.<init>(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.forClass(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.forClass(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.AbstractGrailsClass.<init>(AbstractGrailsClass.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPlugin$GrailsPluginClass.<init>(AbstractGrailsPlugin.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.initialisePlugin(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.<init>(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.<init>(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:264)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.createGrailsPlugin(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:411)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.findUserPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:436)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.attemptLoadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.loadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader$_loadPlugins_closure2.doCall(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy:103)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader$_loadPlugins_closure2.call(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:342)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader.loadPlugins(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the default version of Java I configured to 1.8 with sdkman was setting with the value of `JAVA_HOME` that my app was using.  I just needed to override the value in my run configuration.

Run > Edit Configurations...

[image]

Comment: For some reason, IntelliJ ignores this too.