# change java version from 1.8.0_161 to 1.8.0_151 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
...$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

...$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I have tried to use multiple versions of java using the answer mentioned is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219323/downgrade-java-version).

```
...$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Downloaded jdk 1.8.0_151 from this link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

Extracted it in `home/b/` then tried the following command as mentioned in the post.

```
...$ export  PATH=/home/b/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:$PATH 

... $ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

I am still getting the same java.

I have also tried:

```
...$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

here is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status

------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

This is my $PATH:

```
...$ echo $PATH

/home/b/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:/home/junaid/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

Should I remove Java and download again? If yes, then how?

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to [here](https://askubuntu.com/)?

Comment: Check if `java` in `/home/b/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:$PATH` is executable.